# Setting a CSS class based on the length of a post title

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I am trying to assign a class to a div if the length of the post title (inside the do block) is less than 22 and another class otherwise. Can anyone give my some pointers? Or perhaps a better way to accomplish this?

```
<div <%= 'class="onelineheading"' if post.title.length < 22 else 'class="twolineheading"' %>>post.title</div>
```

Comment: at least a bit shorter. `<div class="<%= post.title.length < 22 ? :one : :two -%>lineheading">post.title</div>`

Answer (score 2):

I would put such logic into a helper

```
# PostHelper
def title_div(title)
  klass = title.length < 22 ? "short-class" : "long-class"
  content_tag(:div, class: klass) do
    title
  end
end

# View
<%= title_div post.title %>
```